# Scaling LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android, layout

I want to place a WebView in place of a "television's" display (as seen in the picture below). I want the "television" to be always fully visible on the tablet (it should scale the television as a whole).

I have 4 frames of the television.

Top and bottom frame:

- **don't** have the same height
- have the same width

Left and right frame:

- **don't** have the same width
- have the same height

Television must keep width/height ratio.

[image]

I have tried following layout, but it only works on large screen and it does not scale everything down on the smaller tablet screen sizes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3" />
            <android.webkit.WebView
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/webView1" />
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Before even looking at how to solve this, I can tell you that my first approach *would not be* nested linear layouts. That's very bad for numerous reasons, mainly performance. My first approach would be a RelativeLayout. My 2nd would be to see if ConstraintLayout can help me with the AspectRatio constraint it supports.

Comment: @pskink I wouldn't be able to set correct margins for the webview

Comment: Bear in mind that using a 9patch is nice, but will cause overdraw (because the web view will be on top of the ImageView). This may or *may not* be a problem, depending upon your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I recreated your layout with a flat hierarchy. Use this as a starting point. The only part not modeled is the AspectRatio, you'll have to deal with that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_start"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageview_top"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_end"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageview_top"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageview_start"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        />
    <android.webkit.WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/imageview_bottom"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageview_top"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageview_start"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/imageview_end"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**And the AspectRatio?**

ConstraintLayout may probably help you there (more than RelativeLayout). Or you'll have to wrap the WebView in a custom `ViewGroup` that overrides onLayout/onMeasure and does the magic for you.

I have *hardcoded* the images height/width with random DPs but you could wrap content if you have images (I just used the background color so you need to specify a size or the image view will collapse to 0/0.

It looks like this:

[image: Preview]

Comment: I don't consider this solution any "workaround" there's no custom code (and likely no need for one to be honest, if the ImageViews have the correct aspect ratio, then so will the WebView. It's flat and fast, easy to maintain and test. Writing a custom View group can have further implications and unintended side-effects. I've done it, and I've seen it happen. There's nothing wrong until there's a case you didn't think of.